# Trying to stack bars with pyplot -is this a bug?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using the example from the gallery as the basis for a plot that shows income and expenditure. The Pandas DataFrame looks like this:

```
                   exp       inc
Wages         19000.00      0.00
Supplies       3723.60      0.00
Party          1557.70      0.00
Admin           987.50      0.00
Adverts         675.00      0.00
Gifts           511.00      0.00
Internet        231.75      0.00
Oddjobs           0.00   8000.00
Sponsorship       0.00  16900.00
Memberfees        0.00  22050.00
```

I turn the data into the requisite tuples and plot as follows:

```
p1 = plt.bar(ind, Wages, width, color='#FFF7EC')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, Supplies, width, color='#FEE8C8', bottom=Wages)
p3 = plt.bar(ind, Party, width, color='#FDD49E', bottom=Supplies)             
p4 = plt.bar(ind, Admin, width, color='#FDBB84', bottom=Party)      
p5 = plt.bar(ind, Adverts, width, color='#FC8D59', bottom=Admin)
p6 = plt.bar(ind, Gifts, width, color='#EF6548', bottom=Adverts)
p7 = plt.bar(ind, Internet, width, color='#D7301F', bottom=Gifts)
p8 = plt.bar(ind, Oddjobs, width, color='#F7FCF5', bottom=Internet)
p9 = plt.bar(ind, Sponsorship, width, color='#E5F5E0', bottom=Oddjobs)
p10 = plt.bar(ind, Memberfees, width, color='#C7E9C0', bottom=Sponsorship)
```

So far, so good. The image looks like this:

[image: Stacked bars, Income and Expenditure]

But I get 10 bars in the expenditures,the colours don't match the legend and the totals are not correct (should be 26686 for exp, 46950 for inc). Is this a bug, or have I messed up somewhere?

Comment: You are doing this very much the hard way.  Since you are already using Pandas, you could get similar results with `clrs = ['#FFF7EC','#FEE8C8','#FDD49E','#FDBB84','#FC8D59','#EF6548','#D7301F','#F7FCF5', '#E5F5E0','#C7E9C0']
df.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=clrs)` ("df.T" because transposing the data frame is the easiest way to force the stacking correctly)

Comment: Thanks @iayork for the pointer (I imagined I was missing some easy method, but I'm still exploring Pandas). I have just tried your suggestion, but for some reason I can't fathom, I get this:  File "bar_stacked2.py", line 65
    clrs = ['#fff7ec', '#fee8c8', '#fdd49e', '#fdbb84', '#fc8d59', '#ef6548', '#d7301f', '#f7fcf5', '#e5f5e0', '#c7e9c0'​]
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@iayork came up with a perfectly good solution; just leave it to Pandas! (It leaves me wondering how many undocumented features there are in pyplot.) Now if I only knew how to credit his answer....

Answer (score 0):

the stacked bar requires that you cumulatively add the y values thats why, i.e:

```
p1 = plt.bar(x1, y1, width, color='#FFF7EC')
p2 = plt.bar(x2, y2, width, color='#FEE8C8', bottom=y1)
p3 = plt.bar(x3, y3, width, color='#FDD49E', bottom=y1+y2)
```

you need to be adding the y-values of the bottom attribute so you will need to implement a similar pandas solution taking the values in each row
and adding them

let me know if you still want me to elaborate :)

Comment: Of course! Thanks, @marwansrieddine. I was expecting too much out of the box.